# Proof that a linear map T is bounded if and only if the inverse image of the unit ball has nonempty interior

Tags: functional-analysis

(Proof is in the image below) I'm having trouble understanding this proof. Where the 1 is coming from in the second line of the proof? Secondly how is epsilon to the -1 supposed to be interpreted? Is this 1/epsilon, or the inverse image of epsilon. I am trying to use this proposition in the proof of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem and would really appreciate any insight. Additionally, if anyone is aware of another method of proof I would be thankful to hear about it. Thanks!

[image: Screenshot from Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics by Reed and Simon]

Comment: When $x$ is a point in $X$ with $\|x\|_X < \varepsilon$, the point $x+x_0$ is in the ball of radius $\varepsilon$ about $x_0$, which is contained in $T^{-1}[\{y:\|y\|_Y \leq 1\}]$. So $x+x_0$ is in $T^{-1}[\{y:\|y\|_Y \leq 1\}]$, and this means precisely $\|T(x+x_0)\|_Y \leq 1$. Secondly, the "inverse image of epsilon" doesn't make any sense, $\varepsilon$ is a number, not a function. Thus $\varepsilon^{-1} = 1/\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! I’m still a bit confused about how the upper bound in the last line follows from x + x0 residing in the ball. Do you have any insight into this?

Comment: We know that $\|Tx\| \leq 1+\|Tx_0\|$ holds for all $x$ whose norm is less than $\varepsilon$. Now, we claim that $$\|Tx\| \leq \frac{2}{\varepsilon}(1+\|Tx_0\|)\|x\| \tag{$*$}$$ holds **for all $x$**. Well, if $x=0$, then its obvious; but if $x \neq 0$, note that $x' := \frac{\varepsilon}{2\|x\|}x$ has norm less than $\varepsilon$, so $\|Tx'\| \leq 1+\|Tx_0\|$ by the first inequality. Now, is easy to see that $\|Tx'\| = \frac{\varepsilon}{2\|x\|}\|Tx\|$, so multiplying $\|Tx'\| \leq 1+\|Tx_0\|$ by $\frac{2\|x\|}{\varepsilon}$ we get $(*)$.

Comment: Ah of course! It didn't occur to me until your reply how we could claim the inequality holds for all x. All clear now, thanks again :)